# Comment code in Pycharm with a German keyboard

Tags: keyboard, pycharm, comments

Does anybody using a German keyboard have found a solution to this?
Ctrl+/ is not possible since it is necessary to push shift+7 to get the slash. But when I do Ctrl+shift+7 I get a bookmark called 7 on that line. Commenting code is very time wasting like that, especially when commenting xml lines.

Comment: same problem with french layout ("azerty")

Comment: I finally decided to go full time with the us keyboard layout and this was a great decision. This was annoying at start (y/z) but in the end it really boosted my productivity as all special characters for coding are easily accessible.

Comment: @wedi good luck writing German emails on that

Comment: I'm doing it every day. I started with ae oe ue but in the end I made the umlauts appear on long press. Karabiner to the rescue. works for me. :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you have a numberpad on your keyboard you can use Ctrl and the division sign on your numpad.

Found this in the Bugreports pointed out by LazyOne

Comment: thx to @Andreas, first time I found an use to this key, after 25y in computing ;-) but to be honest, we must underline that this solution doesn't work on most notebooks (no numpad)

Comment: For now am at a desktop with a numpad, but note that needed to use the _left_ control key ("strg") on the German keyboard to get this to work (and ÷ from numpad), the right one did nothing

Comment: Same here: "Strg + /" from the PyCharm menu help should be interpreted as pseudo-code. On my hardware it evaluates to "Strg + ÷". 25y here as well :D

Answer (score 20):

Choose another working-for-you shortcut for that action at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Keymap` (just use search field to find the right action).

Other than that: watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-16116
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63779

Comment: Don't know why to downvote this. Best solution for Keyboards without numpad

Answer (score 5):

> Keyboard shortcuts are completely customizable in PyCharm

Following is an instruction given in [PyCharm2017.1 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html):

1. Open the Settings dialog box, and click Keymap.
2. Select one of the pre-configured Keymaps, which you want to use as the base for the new one, and click Copy. Accept the default name, or change it as required.
3. In the content pane of actions, select the desired action.
4. Configure keyboard shortcuts. To do that, follow these steps:
5. Click  /help/img/idea/2017.1/properties.gif on the toolbar, or right-click the selected action, and choose Add Keyboard Shortcut. Enter Keyboard Shortcut dialog box opens.
6. Press the keys to be used as shortcuts. The keystrokes are immediately reflected in the First Stroke field. Optionally, select the check box next to Second Stroke and press keys to be used as alternative keyboard shortcuts. 
   As you press the keys, the Preview field displays the suggested combination of keystrokes, and the Conflicts field displays warnings, if some of the keystrokes are already assigned to the other actions.

Note: Click OK with the mouse pointer to create a shortcut and bind it with an action.

Comment: Since I do not use the bookmarks (yet), I just used this method to override the shift+cmd+7 shortcut. So I have one bookmark less but the desired functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I assigned <kbd>CMD + #</kbd> to line comments on my German notebook keyboard without numpad. I think this is a good mnemonic for python comments although editors use something with `/` in their comment shortcuts (C is a bit older than Python :).

Mac: <kbd>CMD + ,</kbd> `-> Keymap -> search for 'comment' -> right click -> Add Keyboard Shortcut -> press`<kbd>CMD + #</kbd>. (As already outline by [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115734/2898712))

Unfortunately I did not get <kbd>CMD + SHIFT + #</kbd> to work for block comments. There seems to be a <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> problem with pycharms keyboard map.

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Keymap -> Main Menu -> Code -> Comment Actions

(or put 'comment' in search box)

You will see 'Comment with line Comment', remove what is there (right click, remove), add what you want after.

As a beginner, I need only 1 or 2 shortcuts, and one of them is comments, so just delete whatever is your shortcut already assigned to when the window pops up.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by mapping the US keyboard layout (QWERTY) to the fn-key (I don't have numberpad):
[image]

[image]

By pressing first [fn] and then [CMD] + [-] it will comment out the marked code lines in pycharm.
I hope this might help others who don't have a numberpad.